# Second order derivatives: Exterior and Lie

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-operators, multilinear-algebra, exterior-algebra

Maybe it's an odd question caused by some overinterpretation..anyway it's not uncommon encounter in books statements like this one (regarding differences among Exterior Derivative, Lie Derivative and Covariant derivative):

> All three agree on smooth functions.

from https://math.stackexchange.com/a/264422/277873.

But if $f$ is a smooth function its second order Exterior Derivative $d(df)=0$, which is not true for its second order Lie Derivative $L^2_Xf$...so where am I wrong?

Comment: The question is what happens when you do it the second time? The second time you’re no longer differentiating a function, and the definitions of the second differentiation are different.

Comment: Thank you @DeaneYang . So - roughly saying - could we state "All three agree on smooth functions _and for first-order derivation_"?

Comment: They agree on functions. Nothing else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first order derivative in all 3 cases is a 1-form, which means a pointwise linear function of tangent vectors. In particular, the value of $D_vf(x) = \nabla_vf(x) = \mathcal{L}_vf(x)$ depends only on the value of $v$ at $x$ and not on any of its derivatives. The situation changes when you take the differential, covariant derivative, or Lie derivative of a $1$-form. The value of a Lie derivative of a $1$-form with respect to a vector field $v$ at $x$ depends on not only the value of $v$ at $x$ but also its first derivative. The second covariant derivative of a function, if properly defined (it requires a little care), is a $2$-tensor $\nabla^2 f$, which means it is a pointwise bilinear function of two vectors. In particular, the value of $\nabla^2_{vw}f(x)$ depends only on the values of $v$ and $w$ at $x$ and not on any of their derivatives. If the connection is torsion free, as it is for the Levi-Civita connection, then it is a symmetric $2$-tensor. The exterior derivative of a $1$-form is the antisymmetrization of its covariant derivative (assuming the connection to be torsion free). Since the second covariant derivative of a function is symmetric, it follows that $d(df) = 0$.

Comment: Just a note: symmetry of the second covariant derivative of a function does not only depend on the torsion: it requires the curvature to vanish.

Comment: @JackozeeHakkiuz, the second covariant derivative of a function, i.e., its Hessian, is always symmetric even if the curvature is not zero, if the torsion is zero.

Comment: @Deane O, you're right. Sorry, I was thinking of a non-scalar field.