# How can I get the two identities

Tags: differential-geometry

Set $\nabla_{0}$ is the tangential gradient on sphere $S^{N-1}$, and $\Delta_{0}$ is the Laplace-Beltrami operator on $S^{N-1}$, $v,\phi \in C^{2}(S^{N-1})$, $\phi$ is also the first eigenfunction of the Laplace-Beltrami operator $-\Delta_{0}$ in $W_{0}^{1,2}(S_{+}^{N-1})$. where $D^{2}v$ is the Hessian opertor,$g=(g_{i,j})$is the metric tensor on $S^{N-1}$.I want to know why the follownig two identities is satisfied:
1) $D^2 v(\nabla_{0}v,\nabla_{0}\phi)=1/2< \nabla_{0}|\nabla_{0}v|^{2}, \nabla_0\phi > $
2)  $D^{2}\phi + \phi g = 0$

You can read the paper " Ioslated Boundary Singularity of Semilinear Elliptic Equations" appeared in  Calculus of Variations and Partial Differential Equations 2011, My question 
is come from the Theorem 2.1 of this paper, please visit the link http://arxiv.org/pdf/0902.0449.pdf

Comment: It might help you if you used consistent notation. What you write as $D$ and as $\nabla_0$ is the same thing, the covariant derivative. Then it's quite obvious that $\Delta_0$ is actually a trace of the Hessian.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/81203/definitions-of-hessian-in-riemannian-geometry here is proved your first identity.

Comment: The second is discussed in the post: http://cuhkmath.wordpress.com/2011/09/29/a-condition-for-a-riemannian-manifold-to-be-isometric-to-a-sphere/, indeed having such a nontrivial $\phi$ implies that the space must be a round sphere.