# When is the covariant Hessian a symmetric tensor?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, hessian-matrix

This question follows up [another question on this website](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/81203/definitions-of-hessian-in-riemannian-geometry).

Let $M$ be a Riemannian manifold and let $f : M \rightarrow \mathbb R$ be a smooth function. We assume that $\nabla$ is a connection over that manifold. The Hessian of $f$ is the symmetric tensor

$\operatorname{Hess} f = \nabla \nabla f$

The Levi-Civita connection seems to be symmetric, as can be seen from its definition in terms of Christoffel symbols. [see Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hessian_matrix#Generalizations_to_Riemannian_manifolds)

**Question** Under which circumstances the covariant Hessian is a symmetric tensor? Is there an intrinsic way of seeing that the Levi-Civita connection is symmetric?

Comment: The first link in your question does not work.  Also, while $\text{Hess} f = \nabla \nabla f$ is correct, the equation $\text{Hess} f(X,Y) = \nabla_X \nabla_Y f$ is incorrect.  The correct identity is $\text{Hess} f(X,Y) = (\nabla_X \nabla f)(Y)$, where we interpret $\nabla f = df$ as a $1$-form.

Comment: The Hessian is only symmetric if the connection $\nabla$ is torsion-free.

Comment: I would add to @Kajelad comment that the main motivation in for the Levi-Civita connexion to be torsion-free is exactly because we wan Hessians functions to be symmetric.

Comment: The symmetry of the Hessian is a side note in most differential geometry classes but IMHO that property should be framed as the core motivation for the Levi-Civita connection.